# writing a test using moq unit testing framework

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm a bit confused with writing unit tests in C#.  I've written the following class for learning Moq.  I've noticed the [SetUp] is actually a reference from NUnit.  How can I write a test class that only uses one framework or another or whether that's possible?  If I want to use Moq what attributes am I missing to successfully run this test?  I know there's [TestFixture], [TestMethod] etc.. but which one do I use for Moq!
Thanks,
James

```
public class CatalogCommandTests
{
    private Mock<IReferenceData> _mockReferenceData;

    [SetUp]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _mockReferenceData = new Mock<IReferenceData>();
    }

    public void TestMyGetMethodReturnsListOfStrings()
    {
        var contractsList = new List<Contract>();

        _mockReferenceData.Setup(x => x.MyGetMethod()).Returns(contractsList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mock looks good. To get the mock of IReferenceData you have to call _mockReferenceData.Object.

A method decorated with the SetUp Attribute will be executed before each test method is called. 
(See: [Setup](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10)).

If you want that TestMyGetMethodReturnsListOfStrings gets called you have to decorate the method with the Test attribute 
(See: [Test](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=test&r=2.2.10)).

Comment: Btw. You have to use 2 Frameworks when you want to use Moq, because Moq is only a mocking framework not a UnitTest Framework. 
If you really want to use only one framework you could use Nunit.Mocks instead of Moq… but Nunit.Mocks is very limited (I wouldn’t use it)

Comment: ok this is the answer I was looking for.  I see, so moq is a mocking framework not an actual unit test writing framework

Comment: also, my visual studio express 2012 for windows desktop is not allowing me to run my tests.  I've added [TestClass] onto the class although it's not recognised?  I've added NUnit.Framework and Moq as my usings..

Comment: update, just added using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; and seems to of made a difference

Comment: [TestClass] is the attribute for visual studio unittesting, NUnit uses [TestFixture] (See: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.2.10)